# How to list drives (HDD, USB, SD, CD/DVD) in Java?

Tags: java, windows, javafx

i'm trying to get a list of currently plugged storage drives on Windows using Java.

Here's the code snippet i've found on another question here on StackOverflow:

```
File[] paths;
FileSystemView fsv = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();

// returns pathnames for files and directory
paths = File.listRoots();

// for each pathname in pathname array
for(File path:paths)
{
    // prints file and directory paths
    System.out.println("Drive Name: "+path);
    System.out.println("Description: "+fsv.getSystemTypeDescription(path));
}
```

The problem is actually that i'm not able to use FileSystemView somehow and i can't import it's library as well...
Could it be because i'm using JavaFX?
Is there any possible solution to this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `FileSystemView` is a Swing class. Is this a Swing application or a JavaFX application? Doesn't the code that actually gives you the list of drives (i.e. `File.listRoots()`) work anyway?

Comment: To use FileSystemView simply add the import `import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;` it is part of the standard jre/jdk. Are you using a lite JDK?

Comment: @sorifiend It's part of the standard JDK, but it's in a separate module (`java.desktop`), so the OP would need to require that module. But it's not a good idea to mix Swing and JavaFX unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Hi, first of all thank you both for replying. It's a JavaFX project but if it's not a good idea to mix JavaFX and Swing, is there a solution that doesn't require Swing to be mixed with JavaFX?

Comment: I'm not on Windows (and all of this is highly platform-dependent), so I can't test this out, but consider using the `java.nio.file` API (which is in the base module). You can do `FileSystem fs = FileSystems.getDefault();` and then, e.g. `fs.getRootDirectories().forEach(System.out::println);` or `fs.getFileStores().forEach(store -> System.out.println(store.name()+" : "+store.type()));` The `FileStore` class has lots of other useful information about the underlying storage (usable space, available space, etc.). See the docs.

Comment: *"is there a solution that doesn't require Swing to be mixed with JavaFX"*. Maybe I'm missing something, but doesn't `File.getRoots()` give you what you need anyway?

Comment: Reopening because the linked Q/A is *very* old (more than 12 years) and relies on an additional module (albeit one that is a `javafx.base` dependency). I think there are ways to achieve this without that dependency.

Answer (score 7):

This is not tested, because I don't have access to a Windows system, but a solution that does not introduce a dependency on the Swing class `FileSystemView` is to use the `java.nio.file` API.

You can get a list of all root directories from the file system with:

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystems.getDefault();
for (Path root : fs.getRootDirectories()) {
    // ...
}
```

You can find the underlying file store for each root directory using `Files.getFileStore(...)` and then query the file store for whatever you need:

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystems.getDefault();
for (Path root : fs.getRootDirectories()) {
    FileStore store = Files.getFileStore(root);
    System.out.printf("Root: %s; File Store: %s; Total space: %d; Type: %s%n",
        root, store.name(), store.getTotalSpace(), store.type());
}
```

---

If you don't mind the additional dependency, add

```
requires java.desktop ;
```

to your `module-info.java` and then import `FileSystemView` with

```
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView ;
```

Comment: Is there any way to catch storage plugged/unplugged in order to update this drives list when needed?

Comment: @ThomasBasile Not that I can see (other than polling, e.g. with a `ScheduledService` etc). On Mac you can register a `WatchService` with `/Volumes` (which will change content when devices are [un]plugged) but afaik there is no equivalent directory structure on windows, and the `FileSystem` itself is not `Watchable`.